# Java program to run shell commands from a windows machine

Tags: java, shell, runtime.exec

I am trying to run a Java program to shell out commands on a remote (Linux) machine. I can get the putty.exe to run and then connect to the machine using SSH keys. But am not able to run the actual commands such as "bash" "ps-ef" or "ls -la". Currently using the Java runtime.exec, not sure if using the `java.lang.ProcessBuilder` would help? What am I doing wrong ? Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated.. Thanks in advance

```
package hello;

import java.io.*;
public class RuntimeExample {




     public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {



    try{     


    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process process = runtime.exec(new String[]{"C:\\Users\\yky90455\\Desktop\\putty.exe","abc@login.testserver.helloworld.co.uk","bash", "ps -ef"});


    InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line;

    System.out.printf("Output of running the command is:");

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);

      }                                                             

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}   

}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a SSH library for that, instead of using putty?

Comment: The whole point of Java is abstract _away from_ the OS.  Always search for a platform independent alternative before resorting to calling native commands. In your example simply use an SSH implementation for Java - such as [sshj](https://github.com/hierynomus/sshj).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I will check out sshj and Jsch.

Comment: Begs the next question, possibly another thread. What is the best SSH library that will facilitate using SSH keys to connect to a remote linux machine and execute commands

Answer (score 2):

try Jsch [From here](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) to get the shell scrips executed from Java to some remote Linux machine. I have worked on this and it was really fun.although you may find little shortage of docs for understanding this but you can overcome that easily.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I will check out sshj and Jsch.

Comment: @joule_wonder: Welcome.But make sure to mark this answer if you go for Jsch :)

Answer (score 0):

Also consider ExpectJ which is a wrapper around TCL Expect. The project does not appear to have any active development since mid 2010, but I have used it for SSH in the past.

http://expectj.sourceforge.net/apidocs/expectj/SshSpawn.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your answers. I tried [Ganymed SSH-2](http://www.ganymed.ethz.ch/ssh2/) library. It works well for the basic commands on the remote machine. I will have to explore other APIs in case I run into any limitation with SSH-2.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class triggerPutty {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        try {
            String command = "putty.exe user@abc.text.com -pw password -m C:\\containing_comman.txt";
            Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process p = null;
            p = r.exec(command);
            p.waitFor();
            p.destroy();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    
    }
}
```

-m helps to run your command from that file. 

You can keep N number of commands in that file.. ## Heading ##

Comment: Consider improving your answer. [Code-only answers may fall under 'Very Low Quality' ...and are candidates for deletion....We've always touted that we aren't a code factory. We are the people who teach others to fish. Code-only answers only feed a person for a day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques)